# Numbered list inside a table cell

Tags: tables, enumerate

How can I insert a numbered list inside a table cell?

I want to show a comparison between two different procedures and how they alter a set of sequences.

Comment: Cells had to be type of `parbox`, i.e. `p{...}` or `X` from `tabularx`, than use `itemize` environment. issues about vertical spaces can be elegant solved with used of `enumitem` package. If you will provide, what you try so far, we can help you where you stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either a `p{}` type column or just insert parboxes around.

Option 1:

[image: option1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{.45\textwidth}p{.45\textwidth}}
        \toprule Head & Head\\\midrule
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Test
            \item Second
        \end{enumerate} & \begin{enumerate}
            \item Test
            \item Second
            \item Third
        \end{enumerate}\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Option 2:

[image: option2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule Head & Head\\\midrule
        \parbox{.45\textwidth}{\begin{enumerate}
            \item Test
            \item Second
        \end{enumerate}} & \parbox{.45\textwidth}{\begin{enumerate}
            \item Test
            \item Second
            \item Third
        \end{enumerate}}\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Further comment: You can use the `enumitem` package and then use the `leftmargin=*` option to remove the space left of the environments. That's one of the aspects Bernard mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some improvements, with `tabularx`,`enumitem` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}%
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
        \usepackage{etoolbox} %
        \AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\setlist[enumerate, 1]{wide, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, before=\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip +2 \partopsep}, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
        \toprule %
        \thead{Head} & \thead{Head}\\%
        \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){1-2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Test
            \item Second
        \end{enumerate} & \begin{enumerate}%
            \item Test
            \item Second
            \item Third
        \end{enumerate}\\%
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What are the improvements here?

Comment: @drozzy The improvements are less space at top and bottom as well as the omitted indentation on the left side.

Comment: It still looks a bit weird. In particular, the mid line is shorter than the outer two lines.

Comment: It is on purpose (obtained with `(lr)` in the code). I think it looks nicer, but if you don't want it, replace`\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){1-2}` with a plain `\midrule`.

Comment: @Bernard Please find the code snippet [here](https://pastebin.com/yQNX6URi). I only want some changes in the second column of second and third row. I want to use `enumerate` lists there to have a left margin for the extra long lines. How do I achieve that keeping all the formatting options existing already in the table? PS: `\rownum` is a row counter defined earlier.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul: I've taken a look at your code, but it is not compilable without completing it. Could you  ask specific questions and post a small complete code?

Comment: @Bernard I have updated my code as an [MWE](https://pastebin.com/UG0uvwEz). Please have a look. If it is too different from your answer in this particular question, I will post a new question.