# Create inline numbered list inside a tabular environment

Tags: tables, enumerate

This is my first time asking in this forum. I am a new to Latex.

I know that my question seems similar with [Numbered list inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352586/numbered-list-inside-a-table-cell), but my goal is to make something like this:

[image: Expected result]

So far, with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{array, multirow, blindtext, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\noindent

\title\large\textbf{TITLE HERE $($KAK$)$}

\noindent

\large\textbf{SUB TITLE HERE}\\

\end{center}

\noindent

\begin{tabular}{@{}llp{0.63\textwidth}}
    Material one & : & Explanation One \\
    Material two & : & Explanation two \\ 
    Material three & : & Explanation three \\
    Material four & : & \begin{enumerate}\item \blindtext \item some text here \end{enumerate} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But the end result was:

[image: My first result]

So, how can I make the numbered list inline with the previous text as the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you load the `enumitem` package to create that custom enumerated environment that's very compact.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{array, blindtext, booktabs}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%% Create a very compact enumerated list environment
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum]{label=\arabic*., nosep, wide, 
                 leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
                 before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
                 after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large\textbf{TITLE HERE $($KAK$)$}\\
\large\textbf{SUB TITLE HERE}
\end{center}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll p{0.63\textwidth} @{}}
\toprule
    Material one   & : & Explanation One \\
    Material two   & : & Explanation two \\ 
    Material three & : & Explanation three \\
    Material four  & : & 
       \begin{myenum}
         \item \blindtext 
         \item Some more text here.
       \end{myenum} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Mico's answer, adjusting the vertical spacing by applying the `\lineskip` size, wrapping also in a new `enumerate` list.

In addition, I used

`@{\hskip2\tabcolsep:\hskip2\tabcolsep}` as a replacement for the 2nd column specifier `l`: It inserts the `:` with the correct spacing `2\tabcolsep` to the left and the same to the right of `:`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlist{insidetabenum}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[insidetabenum,1]{wide,topsep=0pt,leftmargin=*,itemsep=0pt,before={\vspace{\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+3\lineskip}},label={\arabic*.}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\noindent

\title\large\textbf{TITLE HERE $($KAK$)$}

\noindent

\large\textbf{SUB TITLE HERE}\\

\end{center}



\noindent

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\hskip2\tabcolsep:\hskip2\tabcolsep}p{0.63\textwidth}}
    Material one  & Explanation One \\
    Material two  & Explanation two \\ 
    Material three & Explanation three \\
    Material four  & 
    \begin{insidetabenum}
    \item 
      \blindtext[2]
    \item some text here \end{insidetabenum}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to point out explicitly what `@{\hskip2\tabcolsep:\hskip2\tabcolsep}` does. :-)

Comment: @Mico: No, I leave that to the OP as an exercise

Answer (score 0):

You also can have this layout with a simpler code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\noindent

\title\large\textbf{TITLE HERE $($KAK$)$}

\noindent

\large\textbf{SUB TITLE HERE}\\

\end{center}



\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\,:\hskip2\tabcolsep} >{\arraybackslash\compress}p{0.63\textwidth}@{}}
    Material one & Explanation One \\
    Material two & Explanation two \\
    Material three & Explanation three \\
    Material four &
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., wide, itemsep=0pt]%
    \item
      \blindtext
    \item some text here
    \end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the body of items to be vertically aligned with the first letter (the L from Lorem, here), add the key `leftmargin=*.